# YouTube Data API v3: Display a random video with a certain viewcount

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to display a random youtube video with a certain number of views as a gimmick for my homepage. For example; a random video with 1000 views.

I have read the documentation for the youtube data api v3 and looked for a solution. Unfortunately I dont found the right approach.

For my understanding, I need to use videos.list or search.list, but Iam not sure.

Of course I have search at google for a solution, but I only found a approach with the v2 api.

So my first question is; It is at all possbile to display a random video with a specify viewcount? I found no possibility on the v3 api for this :(

Can anybody help me to find the right way?

(sorry for my not perfect english, I hope its understandable)

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to search by viewCount, only order the search results by viewCount, which makes searching for videos with 1000 views very difficult if not impossible since the soft limit on search results is 500 videos. :( Adding more search filters would help with this.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I found this website: petittube.com If I understand it right, they show Videos with 0 views. How it is possible? I found only the possiblity to order the search list function with highest to lowest viewcont.

Comment: Well, ordering by lowest viewCount would mean the results would start with videos with 0 views...

Comment: Yes of course... but how it is possible to ordering by lowest viewcount? From the documentation: "order: viewCount – Resources are sorted from highest to lowest number of views." How it is possible to invert the results?

Comment: Sorry I misspoke. It's ordering by date that would start with the newest videos with 0 views.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested it there: developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it
Unfortunately the result shows a video with 20 views. That is not really the latest uploaded video on youtube. Do you know, why it doesnt work?

Comment: It's going to depend on your filters. If you're searching a term where a new video is uploaded every week on average, then yes the newest uploads are going to have some views. The only thing you can do is check if views == 0.

Comment: Of course, but I haven't used any terms. I have try it only with "part=snippet", "maxResults=1" and "order=date". If I try it now, the video in the result have more than 100 views. So, what I have doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's because YouTube doesn't know what to order by date because there is no filter. If you give it a broad search term like 'cats' then the first results will be videos with 0 views.